# NullPointerException Error?

Tags: java

I'm trying to load an image for my game's back ground but Java is throwing a NullPointerException error at me. I'll comment on where it is.

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public static final int windowXY[] = {800, 600};
    public static Dimension windowSize = new Dimension(windowXY[0], windowXY[1]);
    public static String windowName;
    public static String windowNames[] = {"Test1", "Test2"};
    public static Random roll = new Random();
    public static int nameRoll = roll.nextInt(2);
    public static Thread thread;
    public static boolean running;
    public static Graphics g;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start(g);
    }

    public static void start(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("Starting up game...");
        windowName = windowNames[nameRoll];

        System.out.println("Loading window...");

        frame.setSize(windowSize);
        frame.setTitle(windowName);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("Finished loading window..");
        System.out.println("Loading textures...");

        MainImageRenderer.render();

        System.out.println("Finished loading textures...");
        System.out.println("Loading background...");

        //THROWS THE ERROR HERE
        MainImageRenderer.draw(g, MainImageRenderer.background, windowXY[0], windowXY[1]);     

        System.out.println("Finished loading background...");
    }
}
```

MainImageRenderer:

```
public class MainImageRenderer extends Panel {

    public static Image background;

    public MainImageRenderer() {}

    public static void render() {
        try {
            Image background = ImageIO.read(new File("/resources/background.png"));
        }
        catch(IOException ie) {}
    }

    //THIS IS THE METHOD I AM USING 
    public static void draw(Graphics g, Image img, int x, int y) {
        g.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
    }

}
```

I don't know if it's that I don't have the image in the right place. I'm using Eclipse and the resources folder is on the same level as the src folder.

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: Debug and you'll find that `g` will be null

Comment: g is null at the beginining, try to not using static for everything :S

Answer (score 4):

This part of the code is wrong:

```
try
{
    Image background = ImageIO.read(new File("/resources/background.png"));
}
catch(IOException ie)
{ 
}
```

You are creating a local variable `background` when you should be

```
try
{
     background = ImageIO.read(new File("/resources/background.png"));
}
catch(IOException ie)
{
}
```

Since you are *hiding* the static variable `background`, when you go to render the image, `background` was never set.

And also as nybbler commented, `g` is also going to be `null`, which is more directly leading to your immediate problem with the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Also isn't that an absolute path? It should be `./resources...` shouldn't it?

Comment: Very well might be. I always have to double check when loading resources like this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra `/` and you are good to go....

```
new File("/resources/background.png")
```

change to

```
   new File("resources/background.png")
```

I would recommend this by the way...which is helpful when you package....

```
 URL url=this.getClass().getResource("resources/background.png");
 BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
```

It seems your code has multiple issues....

Instance object types default to `null` when not initialized...Your `g` hasn't been initialized with non-null object..

Answer (score 0):

`background` is null since `ImageIO.read(...)` is throwing an Exception (which you are not doing anything about)